# Angular.copy function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I noticed the following code recently in an Angular tutorial...

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="formCtrl">
  <form novalidate>
    First Name:<br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.firstName"><br>
    Last Name:<br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.lastName">
    <br><br>
    <button ng-click="reset()">RESET</button>
  </form>
  <p>form = {{user}}</p>
  <p>master = {{master}}</p>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('formCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.master = {firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe"};
    $scope.reset = function() {
        $scope.user = angular.copy($scope.master);
    };
    $scope.reset();
});
</script>
```

With respect to the line: `$scope.user = angular.copy($scope.master);`, could this not have been simplified to: `$scope.user = $scope.master;` seeing that `$scope.master` is going to be an immutable constant in this case?

Comment: nope. copy makes a new object

Comment: Okay, so how are the two versions of that statement different? Wouldn't `$scope.user = $scope.master` do the same thing, and if not, what would this statement do in comparison to the `angular.copy()` version?

Comment: You also have to remember that Angular uses 2-way data binding. If you just use = then any changes made to scope.user would be reflected in scope.master. If you're a picky about semantics, the fact that the one is named "master" is indicative that it is the base model for all others to be copied from. You would not expect a child to change the parent. Therefore, a copy is made.

Comment: Also, to the person that downvoted a legitimate question, you should remember that just because it is "blatantly obvious" to you does not mean that everyone else should know it.

Comment: @MBielski I appreciate the support... I've only just started learning AngularJS as of yesterday... I hadn't reached anything in relation to two-way data binding as yet; so thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 3):

When you do `=` in JavaScript with objects, you are only assigning the reference, not creating a new object (new reference). `angular.copy` creates a new object in this case.

In code terms:

```
var obj1 = {}, var obj2 = {}
obj1 !== obj2; // true
obj1 = obj2;
obj1 === obj2; // true
obj1 = angular.clone(obj2);
obj1 !== obj2; // true
```

Comment: To add to this awesome answer for clarity for the OP, if you were to do `$scope.user = $scope.master` and you mutated `$scope.user` later, you would also end up mutating `$scope.master`. `angular.copy` directly copies every key and value from the object into a completely new object.